# FAST get 10 to the power n(10^n) in C/C++

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, double, pow

I want to calculate 10(yes only 10) to the power n[0..308] fast. i came up with some methods.

1)

```
double f(int n) {
  return pow(10.0, n);
}
double f1(int n) {
  double a = 10.0;
  double res = 1.0;
  while(n) {
    if(n&1) res *= a;
    a *= a;
    n >>= 1;
  }
  return res;
}
```

time: O(logn), could it be faster? ( // f1() can do a little bit optimization but still O(logn))

2)

```
double f2(int n) {
  static const double e[] = { 1e+0, 1e+1, 1e+2, ..., 1e+308 };
  return e[n];
}
```

time: O(1), very good.
But space: 309 * 8 bytes = 2472 bytes.. whoops it's too huge...

3)

```
double f3(int n){
    static const double e[] = {
        1e+1, 1e+2, 1e+4, 1e+8, 1e+16, 1e+32, 1e+64, 1e+128, 1e+256
    };
    double res = 1.0;
    for(int i = 0; n; ++i){
        if(n & 1){
            res *= e[i];
        }
        n >>= 1;
    }
    return res;
}
```

f3 combines f1 and f2 to avoid multiplication such as 1e128*1e128, i wished it faster, but.. actually f3 is slower than f2.. because of ++i i guess..

well i almost gave up before i typed these codes,

```
int main(){
    double d = 1e+2;
    return 0;
}
```

and compiled it to .s by g++

```
LCPI0_0:
    .quad   0x4059000000000000              ## double 100
```

HOW does the compiler know 1e+2 is 0x4059000000000000?

i mean all i want to get is a double values 1e+n. but when a compiler compiles "double d = 1e+2", it know d should be 0x4059000000000000. can i just use some method to directly return something like 1e+n. OR can i do some things beyond C/C++ to get my value?

thanks a lot. Please point out if there is something wrong or unclear.

Comment: Is your question how the compiler knows how to store `1e+2`? Perhaps [this](https://godbolt.org/z/ejqc9bWY3) will shed some light on it.

Comment: `1e+2` is a double *literal* – how could a compiler do its work if it wasn't able to translate literals to their IEEE 754 representation (or whatever representation might be used else on a concrete machine, IEEE 754 is not mandatory...).

Comment: If this is performance critical and not embedded on some tiny hardware, the table in f2 doesn't seem huge. Note that you could also have a smaller table, say up to 32, split n as a+b<<5, and do 2 lookups, to get something intermediate in size and speed.

Comment: do you do that a lot? If yes then SIMD would be the better solution

Answer (score 0):

> HOW does the compiler know 1e+2 is 0x4059000000000000?

Because `1e+2` is a literal (so a compile-time constant) and the compiler know the target architecture. Thus it can directly store the constant in the target program. Note that it can compute constants like `pow(10.0, n)` if it can deduce the value of `n` at compile time and optimizations are enabled. Because, `n` is likely a *variable*, 10e+n needs to be computed at *runtime* (eg. using `pow(10.0, n)` like you did for example). If you know that the input `n` is always a compile-time constant, then you can use `constexpr` (or templates).

> f3 combines f1 and f2 to avoid multiplication such as 1e128*1e128, i wished it faster, but.. actually f3 is slower than f2.. because of ++i i guess..

No, it is a bit more complex. `f3` is not very fast because of the loop-carried dependency that prevent your processor to execute the loop efficiently. Indeed, modern processors are [*superscalar*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superscalar_processor) and they can execute many loop iterations *in parallel* as long as there is no dependency between the instructions. In this case, the bottleneck come from the (fully sequential) modification of `res` in each iteration combined with a high latency of the associated floating-point instruction.

Note that the *predictability* of the conditionals and loops also plays a significant role.

> I want to calculate 10(yes only 10) to the power n[0..308] fast

`f2` can be very fast if the table is already stored in the L1 cache (and so can fit inside). Almost all mainstream modern processors have at least 16 KiB of cache nowadays. `f2` can be slower than `f3` if the table is stored in RAM and needs to be retrieved to to the cache (causing a very slow *cache miss* due to the high latency of the RAM).

You can speed up the computation of `f3` by a large margin using a manual **reduction** that can be easily **unrolled** by the compiler. Here is an example of code:

```cpp
double f4(uint32_t n) {
    static const double e[] = {
        1e+1, 1e+2, 1e+4, 1e+8, 1e+16, 1e+32, 1e+64, 1e+128, 1e+256
    };

    double p[9];

    for(int i=0 ; i<9 ; ++i)
        p[i] = (n & (1 << i)) ? e[i] : 1.0;

    return ((p[0] * p[4]) * (p[1] * p[5])) * ((p[2] * p[6]) * (p[3] * p[7])) * p[8];
}
```

The compiler Clang produces relatively good instructions for `f4` resulting in a much faster execution. Unfortunately, some compilers like GCC generate a quite bad code for `f4`: they use slow conditional jumps. Still, this reduction-based approach is far from being cheap.

As proposed by @MarcGlisse in the comments, you can do 2 lookups on very-small tables so to get a very fast implementation:

```
double f6(uint32_t n) {
    static const double eLow[] = { 1e+0, 1e+1, 1e+2, 1e+3, 1e+4, 1e+5, 1e+6, 1e+7, 1e+8, 1e+9, 1e+10, 1e+11, 1e+12, 1e+13, 1e+14, 1e+15, 1e+16, 1e+17, 1e+18, 1e+19, 1e+20, 1e+21, 1e+22, 1e+23, 1e+24, 1e+25, 1e+26, 1e+27, 1e+28, 1e+29, 1e+30, 1e+31 };
    static const double eHigh[] = { 1e+0, 1e+32, 1e+64, 1e+96, 1e+128, 1e+160, 1e+192, 1e+224, 1e+256, 1e+288 };
    return eLow[n & 0x1F] * eHigh[n >> 5];
}
```